# angular on-click expand row in the table

Tags: angular, onclick, row, expand

I have below code in the table:

```
<tr *ngFor="let lfiexport of lfilist | filter:searchText">
 <td class="text-left">{{lfiexport.desc | slice:0:100}}</td>
</tr>
```

How to show full string of lfiexport.desc variable onclick?

Comment: You have to set a flag for each element in the array `lfilist` and toggle it on click. For each flag value, hide or show the value with and without the slice pipe.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can you `*ngIf` directive & based on flag you can view full or sliced string

```
<tr *ngFor="let lfiexport of lfilist | filter:searchText">
 <td (click)="fullViewFlag= !fullViewFlag" class="text-left">
<span *ngIf="fullViewFlag">{{lfiexport.desc}}</span>
<span *ngIf="!fullViewFlag">{{lfiexport.desc | slice:0:100}}</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

You can also utilize index by if only particular row description needs to be displayed completely.
Hope this helps

Comment: Dharman, hello. Thanks a lot. this one is working good. Can you please share how index should be implemented to display only particular row?

Comment: I tried to use below: ```<tr *ngFor="let lfiexport of lfilist; let i = index | filter:searchText" [attr.data-index]="i">``` but it not working